# Cannot migrate sql script with Flyway for Postgres (Java Spring)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, gradle, flyway

I am currently building my application with Spring. And recently stumbled through flyway for db migrations and decided to also implement it into the project.

I have all of my .sql scripts placed under resources/db/migration
The following is how I set up the build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "9.1.6"
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compileOnly 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test'
    user = 'postgres'
    password = 'postgres'
    driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
    schemas = ['public']
    locations = ['filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration/']
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I run `gradle flywayMigrate -i` I kept getting this error:

```
    > Task :flywayMigrate FAILED
    Caching disabled for task ':flywayMigrate' because:
      Build cache is disabled
    Task ':flywayMigrate' is not up-to-date because:
      Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Resolving global dependency management for project 'myapp.main.module'
Excluding []
Excluding []
Excluding []
Excluding []
Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test (PostgreSQL 14.4)
Successfully validated 3 migrations (execution time 00:00.010s)
:flywayMigrate (Thread[Execution worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 0.396 secs.
```

What is it that I still doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Are those 4 lines the only ones you're getting when executing  `gradle flywayMigrate -i`?

Comment: @user3738870 Those 4 were the ones mentioning the error message. However I just updated the output to show the rest of the message.

Comment: To me, it looks like it actually succeeds: "Successfully validated 3 migrations". But what if you add a 4th migration? Will it result in a different output?

Comment: @user3738870 I don't think it is a success since when I looked into my db, I don't see the changes that I implement inside the scripts. Also I got build failed at the very end of the gradle output. And yes I tried adding more scripts, the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself.
Apparently I have to define the schema history table first. This can be done easily first time by adding `baselineOnMigrate` to true inside build.gradle:

```
flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test'
    user = 'postgres'
    password = 'postgres'
    driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
    baselineOnMigrate = true
    locations = ['filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration/']
}
```

I also removed `schemas` as it is not necessarily required in this case.